# Why does not exist the AspectJBeforeAdvice class?

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aspects

In Spring about AOP/AspectJ exists the [MethodInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor.html) interface. It is used internally to decide if an `@Aspect` class must be called or not - really an *advice* method - according with a *pointcut*.

About its implementations exists (see the former link):

- AspectJAfterAdvice
- AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice
- AspectJAroundAdvice

**Question**

What is the reason or Why does not exist the `AspectJBeforeAdvice` class?

Comment: did you miss `AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice`?

Comment: Interesting, it does not appear directly and has a different template class name - your suggested class belongs to other class hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

This is not meant to be a conclusive answer, because I cannot speak for the Spring AOP team or speculate more than just a little bit about their design goals and motives. Insofar, this question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow, because it does not present a programming problem to be solved by a correct answer.

Anyway, actually it seems that the AOP Alliance's `MethodInterceptor` interface is not implemented for before advice types. Either it is not necessary or was an oversight. I think, however, that Spring AOP mostly revolves around the `Advice` interface and, where necessary, its subinterfaces `BeforeAdvice` and `AfterAdvice`. Moreover, all concrete advice types extend `AbstractAspectJAdvice`. This is a screenshot from my IDE:

[image: Advice interface inheritance hierarchy]

Please note on the bottom of the picture, that `MethodInterceptor` itself extends `Interceptor`, which again intercepts `Advice`. So, `Advice` is the common denominator for all advice types, no matter if they are also `MethodInterceptor`s or not.